# ThreeJS | Cannot clone position of object because it appears to be undefined, but that shouldnt be the case

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

my problem lies in the Code below, which might appear to be much, but the real problem lies in the line, between the ERROR APPEARS HERE comments in the code.

The error message I get, is as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

and this refers to the line:

> var originPoint = cubeinschiff.position.clone();

Do you have any idea, on what exatly is wrong with my code?
Please try to explain it in the easiest way to understand, since I am very new to Javascript and Threejs, a few of the things, that are in this Project are things that are copied from the internet. (Such as the Collision Detection)

The full Code below:

```js
 (function() {
   var camera, scene, renderer;
   var enemies = [];
   var enemiesreverse = [];
   var enemiesy = [];
   var enemiesyreverse = [];
   var enemyspeed = 1;
   var nBoxes = 10;
   var listeallerobjekte = [];
   var cubeinschiff;
   var schifftest;
   var collect = [];
   var score = 0;
   var highscore = 0;
   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

     camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
     camera.position.z = 400;

     scene = new THREE.Scene();
     //adding Ship to the scene
     var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
     var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
       color: 'yellow',
       side: THREE.DoubleSide
     });
     objLoader.load('schiff.obj', function(schiff) {
       schiff.traverse(function(child) {

         if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
           child.material = material;
         }

       });
       scene.add(schiff);
       schiff.position.set(0, 0, 0);
       schiff.scale.set(0.03, 0.03, 0.03);
       schiff.rotateX(45);
       schifftest = schiff;
       scene.add(schifftest);
       //adding cube below the ship to the scene(to get the collider detection working)
       var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(25, 25, 25, 1, 1, 1);
       var wireMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
         color: 0xffff00,
         transparent: true,
         opacity: 0.9
       });
       var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, wireMaterial);
       cubeinschiff = cube;
       cube.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
       scene.add(cubeinschiff);
       cubeinschiff.position.x = 20;

     });
     //adding enemies to the scene
     var radius = 1000;
     var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('texture/crate.jpg');

     var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10);
     var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
       map: texture
     });



     for (var i = 0; i < nBoxes; i++) {
       mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       scene.add(mesh);
       mesh.position.set(radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 0.0);
       enemies.push(mesh);
       listeallerobjekte.push(mesh);
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < nBoxes; i++) {
       mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       scene.add(mesh);
       mesh.position.set(radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 0.0);
       enemiesreverse.push(mesh);
       listeallerobjekte.push(mesh);
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < nBoxes; i++) {
       mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       scene.add(mesh);
       mesh.position.set(radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 0.0);
       enemiesy.push(mesh);
       listeallerobjekte.push(mesh);
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < nBoxes; i++) {
       mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
       scene.add(mesh);
       mesh.position.set(radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 0.0);
       enemiesyreverse.push(mesh);
       listeallerobjekte.push(mesh);
     }


     //Adding the stuff to collect to the scene (It is an Array because I need that for the Colliding Detection)
     var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
       color: 0xFFFF00
     });
     var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);

     mesh2.position.set(500 / 2 - 500 * Math.random(), 500 / 2 - 500 * Math.random(), 0.0);
     collect[0] = mesh2;
     scene.add(collect[0]);
     console.log("sammeln activated");



     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
     document.getElementById("webgl").appendChild(renderer.domElement);



     window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

   }

   function onWindowResize() {

     camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

   }

   function animate() {

     requestAnimationFrame(animate);

     //Moving the Enemies
     var radius = 1000;
     for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
       if (enemies[i].position.y < -500) {
         enemies[i].position.set(radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 500, 0.0);
       }
       enemies[i].position.y -= enemyspeed;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < enemiesreverse.length; i++) {
       if (enemiesreverse[i].position.y > 500) {
         enemiesreverse[i].position.set(radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), -500, 0.0);
       }
       enemiesreverse[i].position.y += enemyspeed;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < enemiesy.length; i++) {
       if (enemiesy[i].position.x < -600) {
         enemiesy[i].position.set(600, radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 0.0);
       }
       enemiesy[i].position.x -= enemyspeed;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < enemiesyreverse.length; i++) {
       if (enemiesyreverse[i].position.x > 600) {
         enemiesyreverse[i].position.set(-600, radius / 2 - radius * Math.random(), 0.0);
       }
       enemiesyreverse[i].position.x += enemyspeed;
     }

     //Detecting Collisions
     //ERROR APPEARS HERE
     var originPoint = cubeinschiff.position.clone();
     
     for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < cubeinschiff.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {
       var localVertex = cubeinschiff.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
       var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(cubeinschiff.matrix);
       var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(cubeinschiff.position);

       var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());
       var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(listeallerobjekte);
       //What happnes if an enemy gets hit
       if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {
         if (score > highscore) {
           highscore = score;
           document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = "Highscore: " + highscore;
         }
         score = 0;
         document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
         schifftest.position.set(0, 0, 0);
         cubeinschiff.position.set(20, 0, 0);


       }
       //What happens if you hit the cube that you need to collect for score
       var collisionResults2 = ray.intersectObjects(collect);
       if (collisionResults2.length > 0 && collisionResults2[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {

         collect[0].position.set(500 / 2 - 500 * Math.random(), 500 / 2 - 500 * Math.random(), 0.0);
         score += 1;
         document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
       }

     }
     //Controls for the ship
     $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 87) {
         schifftest.position.y += 0.05;
         cubeinschiff.position.y += 0.05;
         schifftest.rotation.y = 11;
       }
       if (e.keyCode == 83) {
         schifftest.position.y -= 0.05;
         cubeinschiff.position.y -= 0.05;
         schifftest.rotation.y = 33;
       }
       if (e.keyCode == 65) {
         schifftest.position.x -= 0.05;
         cubeinschiff.position.x -= 0.05;
         schifftest.rotation.y = 44;
       }
       if (e.keyCode == 68) {
         schifftest.position.x += 0.05;
         cubeinschiff.position.x += 0.05;
         schifftest.rotation.y = 22;
       }

     });
     //Dont allow the ship to move outside of the game
     if (schifftest.position.x > 500) {
       schifftest.position.x = -500;
       cubeinschiff.position.x = -500 + 20;
     }
     if (schifftest.position.x < -500) {
       schifftest.position.x = 500;
       cubeinschiff.position.x = 500 + 20;
     }
     if (schifftest.position.y < -600) {
       schifftest.position.y = 600;
       cubeinschiff.position.y = 600;
     }
     if (schifftest.position.y > 600) {
       schifftest.position.y = -600;
       cubeinschiff.position.y = -600;
     }

     renderer.render(scene, camera);

   }

 })();
```

Comment: because `var originPoint = cubeinschiff.position.clone();` executes before `schiff.obj` has finished loading and you only set `cubeinschiff = cube;` when loading has finished

Comment: How exactly can I slow down this process then?

Comment: The simplest answer would be to not call the `animate()` function until the `schiff.ojb` has loaded and `cubeinschiff` has been set.

Comment: taking another look at it... why are you even creating `cube` and `cubeinschiff` in the loaded callback? It doesn't seem to rely on the loaded model. Try doing it before loading the .obj

Comment: in addition to @2pha comments: and that's why Three.js has `THREE.LoadingManager()` ([documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders.Managers/LoadingManager)) which allows us to load resources first and then call the function of animation when all is done.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a for loop and do array.push(object[i]); then scene.add(object[i]);
i also have this

```
var abbc = ai2bcz[randur10b0eeezev];

var ac = ai2[randur10b0eeeze];
ac.position.x = abbc.position.x;
ac.position.y = abbc.position.y;
ac.position.z = abbc.position.z;
```